# It seems like you have/You seem to have

Tags: idiomatic-language

**A:** I'm sorry I yelled at you the other night. In my defense, I'd had a long day.

**B:** It seems like you have a lot of those days at the moment. / You seem to have a lot of those days at the moment.

Would both these options be OK in the context or is only one of them idiomatic?

Comment: A should be: "I'm sorry I yelled at you the other night. In my defense, **I** had a long day." And B should be: "it seems like you have **had** a lot of those days **recently**." and "You seem to to have **had** a lot of those days recently" There are other ways to write this, I just chose these corrections. Also, I would argue that, for B, the latter is a bit awkward and I would expect most AmE speakers such as myself to use the former.

Comment: @EliHarold, Your correction for the first one is not quite right - "I'd had a long day" is better to corrected to "I've had a long day" to be grammatically accurate. While it's common to say "I had a long day" - especially in American English - its grammar is not as perfect.

Comment: Just for clarification, "at the moment" is talking about "currently happening", only one "day" can be currently happening, so it doesn't make since to say "a lot of bad days currently" that is why I changed it to "recently" which is likely the most idiomatic way to say this.

Comment: @Onyx he is speaking about "the other night," though. "I've had" implies "today." "I had a bad day" implies a day in the past as intended. If it was "I've had a long day today" then I agree, but in this context it is "I had a long day last week."

Comment: @EliHarold You're right, I overlooked it not being about today as such. But my point still stands and I believe that "I'd had" or "I had had" is more grammatically accurate (if perhaps not colloquial to some areas).

Comment: @Onyx yeah if grammar is the most important I would not phrase it that way at all. I would just say  "in my defense, I had a bad day that day." "had had" sounds very awkward and I personally would never say that. I was mostly trying to highlight the most common/idiomatic version(s).

Comment: **A** is fine as it is. With **B**, "You seem to have a lot of those days at the moment" is a little more idiomatic, if only because it's shorter. We might even shorten _that_ and say, "You seem to have a lot of them at the moment."